# Making a colored box plot without whiskers using D3

Tags: javascript, css, graph, d3.js, bullet-chart

I am new to D3 and am hoping to show a range of prices (lowest price, median price, highest price) for different services using a graph similar to what Glassdoor uses (see this example: http://bit.ly/1koKeLL).

[image]

It's a horizontal bar chart that has a variable margin on the right and left so that it graphically shows the low, median, and high data points. Does anyone know the best way to implement this, especially for someone just learning D3?

Comment: The best way to start is to have a look at the examples on the webpage (or elsewhere) and pick the one that is closest to what you want as a start.

Answer (score 2):

I think this guy implemented very well a chart that is more complex than your chart:

[Bullet Chart in D3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961)

[image]

However, if you want to get to know D3, and to use it in an intelligent and productive way, my strong advice is:

*Don't take shortcuts.*

This means that before you start implementing anything, you go through at least one good tutorial, and take at least brief look at D3 documentation.

A good tutorial is [here](https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3-tutorial). Go through ***ALL*** 20 lessons. Implement ***ALL*** examples on your local machine. You can do it in several days. And only then you come back to your example.

Don't be seduced by stories that you can find on the net like "I started with D3 yesterday, and now I create craziest visualizations". They are either lies or profound ignorance.